# Query count the sum of the rows(last 30 days)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table `p_payments`. The table has the columns `payment_amount`, `payment_status` and `createdtime`:

```
p_payments
____________________________
payment_status      varchar(25)
payment_amount      decimal(7,2)
createdtime         datetime
```

How can I create a query that will count the sum of the last 30 days of revenues `WHERE payment_status = completed`?

My table

```
payments_status     payment_amount     createdtime
----------------------------------------------------------
Completed               1.00           2013-09-29 21:45:02
Denied                  2.00
Failed                  1.50
... etc
```

Comment: the count date is from the actual date?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Sum(payment_amount) 
FROM   p_payments 
WHERE  payments_status = 'completed' 
       AND createdtime >= Date_Sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Comment: Is more elegant to use the `DATE_SUB` function :) instead of -30

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM( p.`payment_amount` ) AS `total_payments`
FROM `payments` p
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.createdtime) <= 30
  AND p.payment_status = 'Completed'
```